# Term used to describe a forced purchase

Tags: terminology

I remember reading an article discussing the idea of paying for medical care - it used a term I can't quite remember, but essentially it described this term being a purchase that people would have to make without considering the actual cost of the purchase because it directly influences their life / longevity.

Can anyone think of what this term was? It was something like a(n) 'XXXX good'. Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe "indispensable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term *essential good* seems to fit the bill, although I would describe it as a *necessary* purchase, rather than *forced*.

> **essential good**
>
> A physical item required by a consumer in order to sustain health or life. Some essential good types that are produced by business operators include food, water, gasoline and heating fuel, as well as residential building materials that can be used to construct homes for shelter.

[Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/essential-good.html)